# How to build hadoop 2.4.0 plugins for eclipse

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I want to build hadoop eclipse plugin for hadoop 2.4.0 version. So how to build this plugin?
I've tried several options of using apache ant, but this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** This commands use to build hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.4.0.jar ***

Steps:

1. Download apache ant http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
2. Download https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin this

***where, root is direcotory of hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin***

hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin
eclipse plugin for hadoop 2.2.0

*** How to build ***

*1) Navigate to this directory*

$cd ***root***\src\contrib\eclipse-plugin

*2) Run this command*

$ant jar -Dversion=2.4.0 -Declipse.home=D:\datatoload\eclipse -Dhadoop.home=C:\hdp\hadoop-2.4.0.2.1.1.0-1621

*** final jar will be genrated at directory ***

$***root***\build\contrib\eclipse-plugin/hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.2.0.jar

** options required ***

eclipse.home: path of eclipse home

hadoop.home: path of hadoop 2.x home

***Important Please set this parameter before trying above ant commands ***

set ANT_HOME=D:\install\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40

set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin